# Why does Eigen's LinSpaced overflow at 46340? (kind of)

Tags: c++, eigen

Eigen has a function `LinSpaced(size, begin, end)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main () {

    cout << ArrayXi::LinSpaced(46342, 0, 46341) << endl;
    /*...
     46338
     46339
     46340
    -46340*/

    cout << ArrayXi::LinSpaced(46341, 1, 46341) << endl;
    /*...
    46338
    46339
    46340
    46341*/

    cout << ArrayXi::LinSpaced(46342, 1, 46342) << endl;
    /*...
     46339
     46340
     46341
    -46339*/

}
```

I'm using 64-bit gcc 6.2.1/clang 3.8.1, no flags, and the latest Eigen from Mercurial. I know that 46340 is the largest number you can square without overflowing a 32-bit integer, but that alone can't account for this cryptic behaviour.

Comment: why did you downvote this question?

Comment: Probably because your example isn't reproducible. Prepare a [mcve], list what system you're using, compiler flags and any other important information. Beyond enabling others to help you, you often end up understanding the issue better and solving it yourself.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, I added my GCC version and I'm not using any compiler flags. Would it help if I added `int main` and some `cout`s?

Comment: Ya, that's what a [mcve] is about. Then others can copy-paste your code and not use assumed code that doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Using your MCVE, I am unable to reproduce your problem (you didn't say what version of Eigen you use). Does the MCVE cause the behavior in the question for you? Can you limit the cases (e.g. different computer, different compiler, different flags, different OS, etc.)?

Comment: This is a shortcoming of a recent "fix": [bug 698](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=698), and of course this has to be fixed!

Comment: And that is why we need to explicitly state library versions. I was testing using 3.2.something. +1 now.